# Unable to import customers from Magento 1.3.1 to Magento 1.9.1. - I get an Error

Tags: import

I tried to EXPORT THE CUSTOMERS from Magento 1.3.1 - I get the csv file but when I try to import it into my new Magento 1.9.1 installation - it gives the following Error:

```
    **Can not find required columns: _website
    Please fix errors and re-upload file**
```

What do I need to do to fix this? Thanks to anyone for suggestions! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There are significant updates from  magento 1.3 to magento 1.4. One of them is the new multistore functionality. In 1.4 and above, website is a required field when doing a customer import. So make a separate column and put your website code there. You can find it in `configuration->stores`.

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot for your idea. You mean to open the CSV file I exported from 1.3 and add a column in there, right? I went to Configuration but don't have STORES in there...do you mean the Current Configuration Scope: Manage Stores on the top left? But the main website is as Main Website - Main Website Store - Default Store View....I think the column has to be labeled and filled very precisely, doesn't it? What should I put for the column heading? website? and for the contents? Thanks a million! ;-)

Comment: @Allysin no, in `System -> Manage Stores` you will find the store id.

Comment: I did this - it says: base --) so - I added a column in the CSV file where in the first line I put: "_website" and then in all the rows: "base" --) Now - I get the following Error: Can not find required columns: email, _website
Please fix errors and re-upload file